How does length contraction account for speed of light between two stopwatches?
I think I understand how length contraction accounts for the measured speed of light being the same in all directions if you measure the speed of light with the "train and two mirrors" method—i.e., you get in a train and stand halfway between two mirrors in the train (aligned with the direction of the motion of the train), shoot a laser at each, and have the lasers bounce off the mirrors and return to you. Relative to you, the two beams simultaneously bounce off the mirrors and simultaneously return to you. Relative to a stationary observer watching the train go by, the two beams do not simultaneously hit the mirrors (the beam going in the opposite direction of the train hits first), but they simultaneously return to you. And relative to the stationary observer, the train is contracted in the direction of motion, and this reduces the time elapsed down to a number that will produce the same constant for the speed of light that your in-train experiment produced.
But I don't see how length contraction accounts for the measured speed of light being the same in all directions if you measure the speed of light with the "two stopwatches" method—i.e., you place two stopwatches, $A$ and $B$, one meter apart and program them to start counting up at the same time (perhaps by sending out two 'start' signals simultaneously), then you get behind $A$ and fire a laser so that it goes through $A$ and then through $B$. (Assume each stopwatch is programmed to stop counting when it receives the laser.) Write down the time difference $\left(\dfrac{1}{299,792,458} \ \text{s}\right)$. Then repeat the experiment firing the laser from the other side, so that it goes through $B$ and then through $A$.
Suppose that the Earth is moving eastward, and when you fire the beam from $B$ to $A$, you are firing it westward. Your pre-scientific brain expects the time difference to be less than $\dfrac{1}{299,792,458} \ \text{s}$, since you are firing the light in the opposite direction of the Earth's motion. But, of course, the time difference is equal to $\dfrac{1}{299,792,458} \ \text{s}$. 
Now, positing length contraction seems like an obviously wrong move here. The time difference is greater than you expected. Trying to solve the problem by positing that your setup has contracted (i.e., $A$ and $B$ are closer together) would make your expectation even further from the mark.
I know I've screwed up somewhere here; if anyone can help, I’d be very grateful. Thank you so much.

Are your clocks synched in the clock frame or the earth frame?

Thank you @WillO, I’m not sure what you mean. What’s the clock frame? (I don't know very much about anything.) Both stopwatches are stationary relative to each other and relative to the earth.

Couldn't they be synced to each other (and to you) by standing halfway between them and firing a start signal in either direction?

@ChrisBandy If the watches and the earth are stationary relative to each other, there's no meaning to the eastward movement of the earth. Eastward with respect to what?

@Amit Ah I see, thank you so much. That makes sense.

I think your confusion starts from assuming that the phenomenon of length contraction is more fundamental than it really is. Length contraction, similarly to time dilation, is better understood as a consequence of the fundamental postulates of special relativity, one of which is the constancy of the speed of light in all inertial frames.
If you start from the postulates, another consequence that you will learn about, in addition to length contraction is the relativity of simultaneity.
In particular, the relativity of simultaneity implies that two events that appear as simultaneous in one inertial frame, will not appear simultaneous in another inertial frame. This excludes the possibility for an inertial observer to arrange two spatially separated clocks that are guaranteed to appear synchronized for other inertial observers.

Thank you, Amir, I appreciate your answer. I guess I am still not getting it. Suppose my experiment were done in the 1880s. Now suppose Lorentz proposed length contractions to explain the phenomena, as he did. Don't you see how that wouldn't help? Proposing length contractions would make the phenomena even more unexpected than it already was. As for my experiment, I am not worried about observers in other inertial frames, if that is what you are referring to. Except for light, everything in my experiment—the earth, me, and the two stopwatches—are motionless relative to each other.

Each watch stops its count when it receives the signal, and the watch visibly displays a decimal number showing where it stopped, so nobody—no matter their reference frame—should have any doubt about when exactly each watch stopped. Unless I am thinking about this wrongly.

@ChrisBandy Yes, Lorentz was the first to propose the idea of length contraction as an ad hoc explanation, to reconcile the hypothesis of the existence of the Aether with experimental findings. However Einstein, by starting from the postulates I mentioned, showed that in fact length contraction is a consequence of what we take today to be deeper physical principles.

Ok thank you. But don't length contractions then contradict the result of the experiment I gave? If length contractions are true, then we'd expect the time difference of the 2nd experiment to be smaller than 1/299,792,458 sec; since the light would have a shorter distance to travel.

@ChrisBandy You're missing the point exactly when you write "Except for light"... no, this is in contradiction to the principles of special relativity. Light has no rest frame so you can't presuppose it exists in some global frame of its own that is moving relative to you.

Thank you Amit, I see my mistake. I think I’m getting there. OK, I have two questions but I’ll do them one at the time. Thank you for bearing with me so far. My first question is: how would Lorentz think that positing length contractions would explain the results of my 2nd experiment? It seems like for my 2nd experiment, positing length expansions would be the more sensible thing to do.

@ChrisBandy Well that's getting quite far afield from your original question :) But, apart from suggesting that you post another question if you see fit, I can also direct you to Wiki's article on the Lorentz ether theory, which we don't take today as part of mainstream physics, but certainly developed much beyond just the concept of length contraction.

Length contraction doesn’t account for it, so your confusion arises from a mistaken assumption. Imagine two stopwatches equidistant from a central point, one to the left and the other to the right. If a light flashes at the centre it will arrive at each watch after an equal delay. Now imagine that viewed from a frame passing to the left. In that frame the light has to travel further to the right hand watch than to the left. Length contraction can’t account for one leg lengthening and the other shortening! And indeed it doesn’t. Instead what accounts for it is the relativity of simultaneity- in the moving frame, light meets the left hand watch before the right, not simultaneously. Effectively the stop watches are out of synch in the moving frame- length contraction is not the answer.

So when you write a question, you should discuss reference frames ($S, S', S'', \cdots$) and events, defined by $(t, x)_S, (t', x')_{S'}, \cdots$.
It appears here, you have a reference frame, which you have chosen to be Earth (not a good choice, Earth rotates--normally we can ignore that, but you have decided to make the Earth's motion meaningful. OK, it's only for $3$ nanoseconds, so we can ignore the motion: but a train is better, it is conceptually inertial).
Then you have two fixed points in the frame, $A$ and $B$. You should introduce their positions first (not after you fired a laser through them).
Anyway, we learn they are aligned west to east. Let's put them on the equator and use ENU coordinates, so they're at $x=-L/2$ and $x=L/2$ (where $L=1$).
To avoid a proliferations of times, I'm going fire both laser at $t=0$, so those events occur at ($T$ is for transmit, and $\pm$ refers to the east coordinate, that is $B$ and $A$):
$$ T^{\mp} = \left(0, \mp \frac L 2 \right). $$
The receive events occur at ($R$ for receive):
$$ R^{\mp} = \left(\frac L c, \pm \frac L 2 \right). $$
So, we have the east speed of light:
$$ v_+ = \frac{R^-_x-T^-_x}{R^-_t-T^-_t}
=\frac{ \dfrac L c}{\dfrac L 2 - \dfrac {-L} 2}= c
$$
$$ v_- = \frac{R^+_x-T^+_x}{R^+_t-T^+_t}
=\frac{ \dfrac L c}{\dfrac {-L} 2 - \dfrac {L} 2}= -c.
$$
That's great. As expected.
Now in the question, do you seem to expect there to be length contraction because the Earth is moving? Moving relative to the center of the Earth. Which is moving relative too?
The Earth's motion doesn't matter: there is no such thing as absolute motion.
If you want to know what this looks like in an inertial frame moving relative to Earth, the Lorentz transform the events.
In a moving frame:
$$ T^+_t \ne T^-_t \quad \text{and}\quad R^+_t \ne R^-_t. $$
If you have a problem with the stop watches (though clocks are fine, no need for stop watches), look at the world lines of each clock:
$$ W^{\pm} = \left(t, \pm \frac L 2 \right). $$

Please try to avoid grammatical errors in your answers, eg "I'm going fire are both laser"

@PM2Ring That's a typo, not a grammatical error.
